# Combinations of a password

Tags: passwords, combinatorics

I am trying to encrypt a password for my school project. Here is the process:

- Let's assume that I have a string `p` (`n` characters long) which contains the password.
- The program reverses the string and stores it in string `r`.
- It takes each character of `p` and `r`, applies the XOR operator and stores it in string `e`.
- Next time the user wants to access the file, she will be asked to enter the password. The entered password will go through the process explained above and will be compared to string `e`.
- If both are not equal, access will be denied.

How many combinations it will take a computer to brute force it, in order to show if it is effective?

**The assignment prevents me from using any third-party libraries such as bcrypt.**

Comment: First things first, passwords should not be encrypted, but hashed. The hashing process is similar to what you are doing right now, though. Second thing, are you required to use your own algorithm for passwords?

Comment: This is for my school project I don't know anything about including hashing in my project. I'm using my own algorithm for passwords because the other algorithm will be hard to include and might require third party applications to do so.

Comment: Most languages have some sort of crypto implementation, whether it be built-in or in third-party libraries. What language are you using?

Comment: For 8-bit ASCII passwords the maximum number would be 256^n so the password (or text) length would be relevant (). Most users won't use anything but letters and maybe numbers. Assuming the attacker would already know it's XOR and has some idea of password length. Not to mention other methods to which XOR cypher would be highly vulnerable. So for short texts it can be brute forced easily for long text it leaves too many clues (like repeating certain patterns, especially when pasword is shorter than the text) that allow other methods to be used. (Also reversing the password is good for nothing)

Comment: @Revenant It's very likely this is a toy assignment for school, meaning no crypto functions may be used, either built-in or external. The purpose is probably to teach the student the complexity and weaknesses of a naive implementation.

Comment: Let's be clear, this is not Encryption. Encryption would involve using a key to obfuscate the password, and it'd be impossible to derive the password without giving the proper key. Yours doesn't even need to be brute forced. If someone found out the method you used to "Encrypt it", they could just reverse the process without needing to have any form of key. In other words, you must assume they have access to the obfuscated version. If they knew the process you just used to obfuscate it, it would take 1 try to get the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No brute forcing is needed. Given the "encrypted" string `e`, I can produce a fake password `p_` which your system will accept, very quickly.

The algorithm to do this is:

- Let `p_first_half` be the first `n/2` characters of `e` (where `/` indicates integer division, rounded down).
- Let `p_` be `p_first_half` with `n - n/2` zero-bytes appended.

If you run `p_` through your "encryption" algorithm, the result will be `e`, so your system will accept my fake password.